# Error while connecting to sybase database using dbd:sybase

Tags: perl, sybase, perl-module, dbd

I have compiled dbd-sybase module(1.07) to add it to  my perl(5.12.3) on windows. However, when I trying to use it using following script:

```
use DBI;
DBD::Sybase;
 $ENV{SYBASE} = 'E:\Sybase';
 $ENV{SYBASE_OCS} = 'OCS-15_0';
$ENV{SYBASE_ASE} = 'ASE-15_0';
$SERVER="ABC";
$DATABASE="dadw";
$USER_NAME="";
$PASSWORD="";

$dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Sybase:server=$SERVER;databse=$DATABASE",$USER_NAME, $PASSWORD);
```

I am getting following error message:

```
install_driver(Sybase) failed: DBD::Sybase initialize: cs_ctx_alloc(113) failed
at c:/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 223.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 4) line 3.

 at b.pl line 11
```

Can someone help in solving this error message.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the driver is using CT-Connect libraries, so I would guess it needs to have valid server information in the interfaces file.

On windows the file is usually located in `C:/sybase/interfaces.ini`

Check this answer for more details on creating interface file entries.

[Using Sybase ASE BCP to a Remote Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529350/using-sybase-ase-bcp-to-a-remote-server/19542698#19542698)

Comment: I see no file named interfaces.ini in my sybase installation

Comment: I added interfaces.ini file with correct file entries. Even then its giving same error message

Answer (score 0):

In Sybase, the interfaces file in Windows is called `sql.ini` and it is located in the **c:Sybase/ini/** folder.